# Silverlight property always return false

Tags: c#, silverlight

On my silverlight project I create this property :

```
private bool _isEnabled = true;
public bool IsEnabled
{
    get
        {
            return _isEnabled;
        }
   set
   {
        _isEnabled = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsEnabled");
    }
}
```

But it always return false instead of true
Why is that ?
Thanks,

Comment: What **precisely** makes you think this is returning false? Have you viewed it in the debugger, logged it, or are you deducing it from some behaviour in your application?

Comment: Sure you arent changing it to be disabled somewhere?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a DependencyProperty?

Comment: I do binding to this property to check box and they always disabled. I put brakepoint on the "set" value and it not gets false from outside. and I put brakepoint on the "get" value and it return false. It is not DependencyProperty it is normal property at the ViewModel

Comment: @Aviv try set a breakpoint on setter to see if your breakpoint being hitted when you click the CheckBox and see if is setting to true. So you know if they are proper binded.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check Your Assigning INotifyPropertyChanged class Like That (inheritance)

```
Public class MainPageVM:INotifyPropertyChanged
```

2) Check Your Xaml Code Mode Property

```
IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled,Mode=TwoWay}"
```